# Objeto no pickleable ejecutando multiprocessing

Tags: python, selenium, multitasking

Tengo un script que scrapea de la web una tabla de datos, de manera que cada nodo  representa una fila, y dentro del tag  se encuentra información que quiero obtener. El código en secuencia lineal funciona bien, pero he decidido intentar a ejecutarlo de manera asíncrona con multiprocessing. Este es el código

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import multiprocessing

def ResPartido(node):

   ft=node.find_element_by_css_selector('.status').text
   if ft.strip()!='FT': return
   hora=node.find_element_by_css_selector('.time').text
   names=list()
   for nam in node.find_elements_by_xpath(
            './/td[contains(@style,"text-align")]/a[contains(@id,"team")]'):
     name=nam.text
     if '(N)' in name:
        name=name.split('(N)')[0]
     names.append(name)
   score=node.find_element_by_css_selector('.red')

   return [hora,name,score.text]

if __name__ == "__main__":

   browser=webdriver.Chrome()
   SOME CODE
   nodes=browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//tr[contains(@align,"center")]/following-sibling::tr[.//div[contains(@class,"toolimg")]]')
   p = multiprocessing.Pool()

   p.map(ResPartido,nodes)   <---Here is the error
   .......

   >>AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encodekey'
```

Como veis, nodes es una lista de todos los tr a scrapear. Si no lo he entendido mal, multiprocessing genera un pool con los node dentro de nodes, y los pasa de manera simultánea a la función ResPartido para que se ejecute su código.

Se supone que las listas si son objetos pickleables, no obstante, me da error en `p.map(ResPartido,nodes)`

[Adjunto captura con el error completo por si fuera de ayuda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5jNj.png)

Comment: ¿Seguro que los objectos node en las listas son *pickleables*? Por ese parece ser el problema. Creo que *webdriver* es más una API que un objeto. Se representa como objeto por facilidad de uso, pero no creo que se pueda pasar entre procesos.

Comment: Eso es lo que sospecho yo, que aunque las listas son objetos pickleables, al ser una lista de nodos html de webdriver individualmente no lo sean y por eso de ese problema. Una posible solución debería ser `pathos multiprocessing`, pero ya es un módulo distinto. Funcionaría si utilizo BSoup para convertir el nodo en una string? O hay alguna manera de circunvalar lo que tengo manteniendo la estructura?

Comment: Poniendo más procesos a trabajar no tiene porque conseguir mejoras automáticas, siendo bastante problable que incluso empeore si los contextos de ejecución son algo pesados. En tu código, usas un único "browser" para todos los procesos y esa es su limitación. Procesar más rápido el html puede no tener sentido si donde más se tarda es en renderizar el html y js. Por supuesto que puedes resolver tu problema si usas strings u otro [objeto *pickeable*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

Comment: @ChemaCortes no tengo claro qué sucede cuando 2 procesos acceden al mismo recurso. En teoría acceden los dos, y si no tienes que hacer ningún cambio sobre dicho recurso no hay problema. Es decir, si lo que quiero es buscar y obtener datos de una página concreta cargada en browser debería poder hacerse. El problema es si quiero seguir links y demás. Cómo implementarías una solución con 2 o 4 browsers? Un saludo

Comment: Por su naturaleza, python no ofrece concurrencia en el acceso a los recursos (eg: GIL para CPython). Hay modos de sortear esta limitación (async, multiprocessing,...), pero si me preguntas a mí, te diría que uses otro lenguaje. Selenium está bien para testear aplicaciones web, pero desconozco su comportamiento en multiproceso. En tu hilo principal estás abriendo un browser. Lo puedes compartir con otros hilos en el mismo proceso; pero en multiproceso no queda más remedio que, o bien pasarle los datos serializados (pickle), o bien abrir tantos browsers como procesos tengas.